# how to Create if not exists a new Java DB?

Tags: java, database

```
 conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:mydatabase;create=true",props);
```

will this line make my DB get overwritten everytime i execute it? if it will how do i create the DB once and just use it ever since?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are doing will work with Derby.  It will create the database if it doesn't exist and do nothing if it already does exist.